# Icon of android application is not getting displayed

Tags: xml, android

I made an icon and saved it in res/drawable directory as `icon.png` and edited the line `<application android:label="@string/app_name">` in `AndroidManifest.xml` to `<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">`.

But on restarting the emulator, the icon doesn't get displayed. There are no other `icon.png` files in the project.

AndroidMainifest.xml :-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="android.com.machineInfo"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".machineInfo"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: paste your `AndroidManifest.xml` please

Comment: Do you see the file in Eclipse Package Explorer view? If not F5 (or refresh) can help.

Comment: ya the file is visible.. 
i think my icon doesn't conform to the design guidelines..  http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html#top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have both `res/drawable` and family of `res/drawable-...` (where ... is ldpi, mdpi or hdpi) folders then for standard emulator configuration (HVGA skin) file from `res/drawble-mdpi` has precedence over the one in `res/drawable`.

**edit:**

see: DevGuide

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources